# Graph of $f(x,y) = \frac{3x^2 y}{x^2+y^2}$ near the origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

I am trying to graph the function $f : (x,y) \mapsto \frac{3x^2 y}{x^2+y^2}$ on a TI-89 Titanium.  I have noticed that no matter how many times I zoom in toward the origin the graph appears identical.  I know that $f(x,y)$ is continuous and differentiable everywhere except $(0,0)$ and that $f(x,y)$ approaches $0$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ but I have no idea why the fractal behavior is occurring.

Comment: This is because $f(ax,ay)=af(x,y)$. Basically, if you scale both parameters, you exactly scale the value of the function by the same amount.

Comment: @Narasimham Can you explain what you mean by "homogeneous"

Comment: Does anyone know what "homogeneous" means in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because $f(ax,ay) = af(x,y)$